# How do I add users to tenant via the Graph API?

Tags: azure, office365

I've utilized the Partner Center REST API to provision tenants with orders/subscriptions.  Now I want to start configuring the domains and users for the tenant I just created.  My first step was to get a list of users using the Graph API https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations as a test expecting to see the admin account.  If I pass in the domain of the reseller account in the request URL, it shows me the reseller users.  But when I put in the domain of the account I just provisioned, I get `Invalid domain name in the request url.`  I'm using the resellers AD token to do this.  I'm confused as it gives me the option to specify a domain, but I can only access my own.

What credentials am I supposed to be using here?  I tried to use the user/pass that was generated for the admin account from the provision, but I get `unauthorized_client` when trying to get an AD token from the Graph API.

Comment: 2017 Detail -    **Invalid domain name in the request url.**      If you are seeing this error for the classic Graph call ( https://graph.windows.net/ )  then try switching your tenant guid id for the full domain name in your request url.   This Fails …  https://graph.windows.net/GuidValue/   This Works …  https://graph.windows.net/MyTenantName.onmicrosoft.com/     I also avoid using any variant of “common”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are issues with sandbox accounts and Azure.  Access to the Azure Management Portal for the sandbox isn't straightforward and at this time does not work properly.  I had to create a free Azure account with my hotmail account, then link AD from the new account to my sandbox AD to bypass the bug.  When adding a new directory to the new Azure account, select "Use existing directory", sign out, then sign into the sandbox account you want to link it to.  Then create your app from the new account.

After getting my app setup properly and new credentials, I had to enable pre-consent with the instructions listed at the end of: https://github.com/Microsoft/Partner-Center-Explorer

Lastly, I had to login to the Graph API with the customers ID, but with the resellers credentials.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to directly address your issues here since they are a little broad, and I would need more specific details about the various tenants you are working with, how your app is provisioned, permissions your app has etc...

However I think there a few principals you can follow which may help you debug your issues.

- All AAD Authentication happens within the context of a specific tenant. This means whenever you get an access token for a resource, the scope of that token is limited to the boundaries of the tenant.
- To authenticate with a client application in the context of a tenant, you must have the app registered in the tenant you are trying to access (line of business application / single tenant) or you have to make the app multi-tenant, in which case your app should be able to function in the context of any tenant... if the right provisioning has occurred.
- Every tenant where your app is trying to function must have a service principal for the application provisioned in the tenant. This service principal represents your application's identity in the context of that tenant, and acts as a place to store the permission your application has in the context of that tenant. Most normally, this service principal gets provisioned into a tenant after a user from that tenant has consented to use the app as a part of the login experience.
- If you are trying to use user context (authorization code grant flow) to retrieve details about a tenant, you must ensure that that user is present in the directory you are trying to query. For example a user U can exist in their home tenant T1. If you try to query another tenant T2 using that user account, you will get any number of errors describing that the user account does not exist etc. You can remedy this by creating a guest account for U in T2, in which case there will be a brand new user object created in T2 which links to the original user object in T1. None the less, the user object should always be present in the tenant you are trying to query.
- If you are trying to sign into an application with a user account that is in T1 and T2, you need to be sure to specify the tenant you want to actually get the token for. By default, if you use the common endpoint, you will get a token for the users home tenant. However, it is perfectly valid to get a token for the secondary tenant, as long as you specify that to our Token Service when making the request.
- Finally the client application you use to make these requests needs to have the right permissions to the Graph API if you want to make specific calls to the Graph API. Every tenant needs to individually consent to the application in their tenant context in order to provision the correct permissions to their application.

With those principals in mind:
The error you are getting with "unauthorized_client" seems to be an issue with application provisioning in the secondary tenant. Please make sure to first login to the application with a user from the secondary tenant, and make sure that user has the correct permissions to consent to your app (a tenant admin is best here).

For the second issue with "Invalid domain name in the request url" please try using some hints [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-operations-overview).
Specifically this:

> By using the myOrganization alias. This alias is only available when using OAuth Authorization Code Grant type (3-legged) authentication; that is, when using a delegated permission scope. The alias is not case sensitive. It replaces the object ID or tenant domain in the URL. When the alias is used, Graph API derives the tenant from the claims presented in the token attached to the request. The following URL shows how to address the users resource collection of a tenant using this alias: 
>   https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?api-version=1.6.

I hope this puts you on the correct path to resolve most of your issues.

Answer (score 0):

The [scenarios on the Partner Center SDK website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/partnercenter/mt634715.aspx) include a section "Manage user accounts and assign licenses" under the "Manage customer accounts" section.

These samples include creating users and assigning licenses and a link to a console test app.

As an aside, a new version of the Partner Center SDK has just become available [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Store.PartnerCenter/). It was released on July 5th. While there is no official change history that I can find, I can see that it includes some new classes such as CustomerUser. You may find it easier to use that library rather than hitting the REST API (depending on how much work you've already done).

Comment: I've seen the changes.  Some of the user functionality that I have for the graph API now works in the partner center.  I haven't tried it, it seems odd since I have to verify a domain before adding my users and there is no domain feature in the partner center yet.  Maybe this limitation isn't in the new changes.  I'll find out if I get to changing it.  As far as skipping REST...the SDK is just a C# REST wrapper, and I'm in python.